# Mock return values of a function of mock object

Tags: python

I am writing unit tests. I would like to mock the result of a function called on a mock object.

I have a class called `OwnerAnalyzer` which accepts an object called `client` in its constructor. Using this client, I can get `owner` details.

In my unit test, I want to pass a mock for this client and mock results from its `get_owners` method.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def test_get_owner_details(mock_datetime, monkeypatch):
    mock_datetime.now.return_value.isoformat.return_value = MOCK_NOW
    mock_client = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_client.return_value.get_owners.return_value = ListOwnerDetails(
        main_owner=OwnerDetails(name='test_owner', type='User'), secondary_owners=[])

    owner_analyzer = OwnerAnalyzer(OWNER_NAME, client=mock_client)
    owner_analyzer.analyze_owner(OWNER_NAME)
    assert classUnderTest.owner_name == 'test_owner'
```

I don't think the mock value is being returned in the `get_owners` call because I get something like for `main_owner`
`owner is : <MagicMock name='mock.get_owners().main_owner' id='140420863948896'>`.

Comment: You're setting up `mock().get_owners()`, not `mock.get_owners()`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow.

Comment: Look at the representation of the mock you're actually getting. Compare it to the mock you've set up. Do you expect the OwnerAnalyzer to *call* the client?

Comment: The method `analyze_owner` in OwnerAnalyzer calls `client.get_owners` using `self.client` of OwnerAnalyzer. That is the call I want to mock. Sorry, I am new to Python, I usually code in Java.

Comment: Yes, but you're setting up the mock on *the return value of `client()`*. Again, *look* at what the output is telling you and think about how the code under test is going to interact with your test doubles.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will closely into my mock setup.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe for pointing me in the right direction.

I was able to get this working by updating my mock setup to -

```
mock_client.get_owners.return_value = ListOwnerDetails(
        main_owner=OwnerDetails(name='test_owner', type='User'), secondary_owners=[])
```